# Angularjs - Unknown provider: $cordovaGeolocationProvider

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use  $cordovaGeolocation but it give below error. Any one can help?

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaGeolocationProvider <-    $cordovaGeolocation <- GeoCtrl
```

I used sample in [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/)

Comment: did you include 'ngCordova' dependency in your `angular.module` declaration?

Comment: No i was not including 'ngCordova'. But after your comment i added then it failed again. And then after googled, i downloaded ngCordova file [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) and it worked now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you be so kind to upvote after I update to an answer?

Comment: did. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing a little setup. First, download `ngCordova.js` and include it in your `index.html` right before all your Angular scripts. Then, include the 'ngCordova' dependency when you declare your app module like this: `angular.module('yourAppName', ['ngCordova', ...])`